# webkitAudioContext createMediaElementSource on iOS Safari not working

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, webkit, webkitaudiocontext

I want to do a live sound analysis on the iPhone. Therefor I use
the webkitAudioContext Analyser.

```
var ctx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
var audioGoodmorning = new Audio('assets/sounds/greeting.m4a');
var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioGoodmorning);
var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();

analyser.fftSize = 32;
audioSrc.connect(analyser);
audioSrc.connect(ctx.destination);
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.fftSize);

analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
```

This works well in Chrome on Mac. It also works on Safari, when adding the Website to the homescreen, with

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CHAR">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
```

It doesn't work on Safari without adding the Site to the homescreen.
It doesn't work when using the Site embedded with iOS wkwebview. That is what I want to achieve. 
When not working, the frequencyData Array is full of zeroes.

Anyone having experienced this kinda issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be available according to:
http://caniuse.com/#search=AudioContext you could test using the mozilla example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext but could be the embedded web view is a different build from the browser version

Answer (score 4):

Check this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4b2dvhqy/1/

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

audio.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
audio.src = "https://greggman.github.io/doodles/sounds/DOCTOR VOX - Level Up.mp3";
audio.play();
audio.controls = true;

document.getElementById("wrapper").append(audio);

audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
  var audioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);

  audioSourceNode.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
});
```

It's working fine on Safari because the Audio stuff is handled under a user click event.

Without the "user click event", it's working fine on Chrome or Safari "localhost" only.

Also, this other Fiddle is working fine with HTML tag audio:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbua1pkn/1/

The trick here is to initialize the audioContext when user click on play button! (so you are under a user event context).

Comment: The jsfiddle example does not work for me in mobile safari (press play; nothing plays).

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in iOS 13 where users can't call createMediaElementSource on a <audio/> or <video/> element.  It just refuses to play the content after you've called that function and the node doesn't produce any output.  You can find more info here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211394

Answer (score -3):

Just in case this hasn't been solved yet, according to https://caniuse.com/#search=webaudio Safari still doesn't support `createMediaElementSource`, so I think you're out of luck here. Safari's support for the WebAudio API is not great, unfortunately.